# RegEx validation of techmahindra account

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex, ipad

I want to validate for `textfield` of email and wants to find out is it techmahindra email or not. How can I find it . I am attaching my code here.
Could any one suggest changes.

```
NSString * myString = @ "@";
NSArray * myWords = [emailStr componentsSeparatedByString: myString];

NSString * str = [myWords objectAtIndex: 1];

if ([str isEqualToString: @ "techmahindra.com"]) {
    NSString * emailRegex = @ "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+]+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate * emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @ "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject: emailStr];
} else
    return NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have written code to extract the part of the string that follows the @ symbol, you don't need regular expressions there. You can simply do a case-insensitive comparison, like this:

```
if (str != nil && [str compare:@"techmahindra.com" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]) {
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailStr];
}
else
    return NO;
```

You probably should also trim whitespace as part of your email validation code as this check will fail if there is a trailing space for example.

Comment: Thanks for your post but is there something which will validate the email is gmail or not, techmahindra or not like that. And what should be written in the regular expression

Comment: I think the simplest way to validate against specific email domains is to have a list of such domains (all lowercase), process your email address to extract its domain in lowercase, then check if your array contains it.  Regular expressions get complicated pretty quickly and become a maintenance nightmare when you want to update your criteria.